# How can I align a background image to the left of centered text in an h1?

Tags: html, css

I need to align an image just to the left of some text in an h1. So imagine it's something like:

[logo image] Company

So it isn't really a "background"--it's more of a foreground image.

This works if the h1 is left-aligned, using padding to offset the text from the image:

```
h1 {
  background: url("logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

However, I also want to center the text. I can do that as follows, but the image is still left-aligned:

```
h1 {
  background: url("logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In other words, the text is in the center of the screen, but the image is still on the left margin.

How can I keep the image centered, but just to the left of the text? I don't want to get too tricky with absolute pixel values, or a fixed-width h1, as this all needs to be relative and responsive.

I can't center the background image, as it needs an offset for the h1 text, which needs to scale.

Should I just slap an img tag in there and be done with this?

Another option would be to make the whole thing an image, but I want the text to scale--it's actually more of a caption than a logo.

[Note: I googled a bunch but most of the links deal with the "centered h1 over a large background image" scenario, which this isn't. Thanks!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how big everything is you could try it with background-position porperty and then give % value to x.

```
h1 {
background: url("logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
line-height: 70px;
padding-left: 80px;
text-align: center;
background-position:20% (e.g.);
}
```

But to be honest, i would recommend using an image tag. You can give that image some responsiveness like done in bootstrap [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images)

Comment: It doesn't seem like the most "elegant" solution but I'll just stick with the img tag in this case, as the other stuff feels somewhat fiddly and brittle. Thanks to everyone for your time and effort--I've tried to share the love. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**

```
h1 {
    background: no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before {
    content: url("logo.png");
    float: left;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQ8T/3/**

I learned something new about the `content` CSS here, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer (upvoted). It's still left-aligned though, presumably because the h1 is 100% width (unset).

Comment: @TK-421 if you remove the `float:left;` does this give you what you want? If not I think a little clarification might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h1::before {
    content: url("http://placekitten.com/200/80");
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Since you know the image dimensions, you can play with negative `margin-left`. As you can see, the text alignment is NOT affected by the image. Is that what you wanted to achieve?

**[Here's the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LgxRx/)**

Comment: Interestingly, the negative left margin is skewing the text off-center. I can set the margin-left to 0 and the text is better centered and the image remains just to the left, or even remove all the attributes except content and the effect is roughly the same.

Comment: But notice that then the image will be also considered to the alignment. Is that what you wanted? Say, the image is 1000px wide and text takes up space of 150px. If the window size is 1024px the whole `h1` won't fit. With my solution instead, the text will have plenty of space on both sides, while the image will stay next to it on the left side.

Comment: This is something I'll consider, but think I'm over-complicating things and will just use an img tag. Thanks for the time and assistance (upvoted)!

Answer (score 1):

there are several options already, and this one comes with an "IF" but i'm adding it here for variety.

**If** you can specify the width of the H1 tag then you can use `padding` and `margin:auto` to achieve this.

```
h1#elementID {
    background-image: url("img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    width: 165px;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
```

adjusting the width / padding to fit your text image.  It may improve scaling if you use something besides px as your sizing mechanism.

Comment: I didn't want to get into sizing the h1, but I suppose I could make it a percentage width...

Comment: careful on small screens as a low % may cause the text to break down.  Sizing with em's might be a good way to control the size depending on how your handling scaling/font-size.

Comment: Thanks--except for the known, fixed image size, I'm using em's or rem's for everything. I'm thinking just go with img tag in this case for better stability/compatibility.